# what does dereference operator return? l-value or r-value

Tags: c

what does dereference operator return? l-value or r-value
based on below example as the increment opearator is working properly. Need an explanation for the same

```
// venukant
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char arr[] = "gendafool";
  char *p = arr;
  ++*p; // evaluated as ++(*p) but ++ requires a l-value 
  printf(" %c", *p); // prints h

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that there are also **not-modifiable lvalues**...

Comment: yes i know about const dont worry

Comment: Arrays are non-modifiable too. The point is, they're lvalues as well.

Comment: This is no duplicat, because the referred question is more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the 1999 C standard, Section 6.3.2.1, para 1 starts with .....

> An lvalue is an expression with an object type or an incomplete type other than void;

and then refers to footnote 53, which says

> The name ‘‘lvalue’’ comes originally from the assignment expression `E1 = E2`, in which the left
>   operand `E1` is required to be a (modifiable) lvalue. It is perhaps better considered as representing an
>   object ‘‘locator value’’. What is sometimes called ‘‘rvalue’’ is in this International Standard described
>   as the ‘‘value of an expression’’.
>
> An obvious example of an lvalue is an identifier of an object. As a further example, if `E` is a unary
>   expression that is a pointer to an object, `*E` is an lvalue that designates the object to which `E` points.

In n1548 (draft of the 2011 standard), the same para starts with something worded slightly differently, but with essentially the same meaning;

> An
>   lvalue
>   is  an  expression  (with  an  object  type  other  than
>   void
>   )that  potentially
>   designates an object;

This para refers to footnote 64, which is identical in content to footnote 53 from the 1999 C standard.

Bear in mind that footnotes in the standard are not normative - their purpose is to clarify and explain.

To answer the original question, the dereference operator (`*p`) produces an lvalue.   However, the value of the expression can be used as an rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

The  unary * produces an lvalue as its result. A non-null pointer p always points to an object, so *p is an lvalue. For example:

```
int a[N];
int *p = a;
...
*p = 3;     // ok
```

Although the result is an lvalue, the operand can be an rvalue, as in:

```
*(p + 1) = 4;    // ok
```

Hope this answers your query.

Comment: you can also check goo.gl/TvENqj

Comment: Unary `&` does not yield an lvalue.

Comment: Yes you are right.. I am sorry for that. unary & requires an lvalue as its operand and  it's result is an rvalue

Comment: Sometimes non-null pointers do not point to objects , e.g. `char *c = malloc(5); free(c);`

Comment: @M.M in the context of the above program with the example you provided we can use strcpy(p, "gendafool");